# Graph $2$-hops stable set

Tags: graph-theory

Let $D=(V,E)$ be a loopless digraph. We say that $S \subset V$ is *$2$-hop stable* if $S$ has these two properties:

1. For each $u,v \in S$, the edge $uv \notin E$.
2. Every vertex $s \in (V-S)$ can be accessed from a vertex $t \in S$ through a path of maximum length $2$.

Show (a) that for any loopless digraph we can find a $2$-hop stable set in  complexity $\operatorname{O}(|V|+|E|)$, and (b) that we can reduce $3$-SAT problem at $P$:

Problem $P$: Let $D=(V,E)$ a digraph and a vertex $T$. Test if there is any $2$-hop stable set which contains $T$.

Comment: 1) means $S$ is an independent set. Sounds like a question I just did.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590568/coloring-problem-on-directed-graph/1590582 (Replace $S$ with white.)